# I am not able to install my Android app on my Samsung galaxy pop

Tags: android, apk

I am facing a strange problem.  I created an apk of my application with unsigned key and tried to install it on my samsung galaxy pop, but i am not able to install it on my samsung galaxy pop. I enabled the option for installation of non market place app but i am getting unable to install message.

However when i am connecting phone with USB and clicking on run it is getting installed in the device.

is there anything wrong in my approach??

this is my sample apk file which i am trying to install http://www.mediafire.com/?aotxfupx7h7t568

Thanks

Comment: Try installing with `adb` so you can see the error message. Navigate to wherever the .apk is on your computer, then run `adb install <package>` with your phone plugged in.

Comment: Please use standard English spelling.  "not", "one", etc.

Comment: @eldarerathis I will try with adb and see the error trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must sign it

From [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)

*The Android system requires that all installed applications be digitally signed with a certificate whose private key is held by the application's developer. The Android system uses the certificate as a means of identifying the author of an application and establishing trust relationships between applications. The certificate is not used to control which applications the user can install. The certificate does not need to be signed by a certificate authority: it is perfectly allowable, and typical, for Android applications to use self-signed certificates.

**All applications must be signed. The system will not install an application that is not signed.**

It couldn't be any clearer

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this from Eclipse and running the app on handset, I think android treats it differently, since you probably had USB debugging enabled and the handset is fooled into thinking it is debugging.

When you tried installing the app, because it is not signed the handset may be rejecting it.

You should be fine running and debugging like this, but when you create the final apk you will need it signed.

Comment: but ideally i should able to distribute unsigned apk?? I will try with adb and will paste the error code.

Comment: @Parry: See [NickT's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572129/i-am-not-able-to-install-my-android-app-on-my-samsung-galaxy-pop/5572644#5572644). The apk needs to be signed. It can be *self-signed*, but it must be signed.